# Get average values ​from a map given a condition

Tags: dart

Given this map:

```
<DateTime, double> {
2014-09-01 01:46:00.000: 1.29, 
2014-09-01 01:47:00.000: 1.27, 
2014-09-01 01:48:00.000: 1.27,
2014-09-01 01:48:00.000: 1.27,
2014-09-01 01:49:00.000: 1.26, 
2014-09-01 01:50:00.000: 1.26,
2014-09-01 01:50:00.000: 1.26,
2014-09-01 01:51:00.000: 1.26, 
2014-09-01 01:52:00.000: 1.26,
2014-09-01 01:52:00.000: 1.26,
2014-09-01 01:53:00.000: 1.26, 
2014-09-01 01:54:00.000: 1.27,
2014-09-01 01:54:00.000: 1.27
}
```

How can i calculate the average of values ​​only where the date repeats, for example:
the date repeats twice for the value 1.26 and 1.27, but with diferent date

```
2014-09-01 01:50:00.000: 1.26,
2014-09-01 01:50:00.000: 1.26,
```

How can I do this on the map?

Comment: What type of `Map` are you using? The default `Map` would most likely not allow you to have multiple `DateTime` pointing to the same point in time as key since you would just end up overwriting the previous entry in the `Map`.

Comment: They are not pointing to the same key, they are just repeated entries with same key and values and it is precisely in these repeated ones that I need to count their occurrences and make the average of the value, even if they are only twice and the value ends up the same

Comment: Can you add a standalone Dart program that declares this map to your question? It would also make it a lot easier for people to write a solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your current maps contains multiple keys that would be considered the same object since `DateTime` overrides `==` and `.hashCode` so two `DateTime`pointing to the same point in time, would be considered equal: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.6/dart-core/DateTime/operator_equals.html

This means if we just try to create the `Map` normally we would end up with:

```dart
void main() {
  final map = <DateTime, double>{
    DateTime.parse('2014-09-01 01:46:00.000'): 1.29,
    DateTime.parse('2014-09-01 01:47:00.000'): 1.27,
    DateTime.parse('2014-09-01 01:48:00.000'): 1.27,
    DateTime.parse('2014-09-01 01:48:00.000'): 1.27,
    DateTime.parse('2014-09-01 01:49:00.000'): 1.26,
    DateTime.parse('2014-09-01 01:50:00.000'): 1.26,
    DateTime.parse('2014-09-01 01:50:00.000'): 1.26,
    DateTime.parse('2014-09-01 01:51:00.000'): 1.26,
    DateTime.parse('2014-09-01 01:52:00.000'): 1.26,
    DateTime.parse('2014-09-01 01:52:00.000'): 1.26,
    DateTime.parse('2014-09-01 01:53:00.000'): 1.26,
    DateTime.parse('2014-09-01 01:54:00.000'): 1.27,
    DateTime.parse('2014-09-01 01:54:00.000'): 1.27,
  };

  print(map.length); // 9
  map.entries.forEach(print);
  // MapEntry(2014-09-01 01:46:00.000: 1.29)
  // MapEntry(2014-09-01 01:47:00.000: 1.27)
  // MapEntry(2014-09-01 01:48:00.000: 1.27)
  // MapEntry(2014-09-01 01:49:00.000: 1.26)
  // MapEntry(2014-09-01 01:50:00.000: 1.26)
  // MapEntry(2014-09-01 01:51:00.000: 1.26)
  // MapEntry(2014-09-01 01:52:00.000: 1.26)
  // MapEntry(2014-09-01 01:53:00.000: 1.26)
  // MapEntry(2014-09-01 01:54:00.000: 1.27)
}
```

So the length ends up being `9` even if we put `13` elements into the `Map`.

We can instead use a `Map.identity()` map where we just looks at the identity  each object key to determine if the key are equal (so we no longer use `==` and `.hashCode`):

```dart
void main() {
  final identityMap = Map<DateTime, double>.identity()
    ..[DateTime.parse('2014-09-01 01:46:00.000')] = 1.29
    ..[DateTime.parse('2014-09-01 01:47:00.000')] = 1.27
    ..[DateTime.parse('2014-09-01 01:48:00.000')] = 1.27
    ..[DateTime.parse('2014-09-01 01:48:00.000')] = 1.26
    ..[DateTime.parse('2014-09-01 01:49:00.000')] = 1.26
    ..[DateTime.parse('2014-09-01 01:50:00.000')] = 1.26
    ..[DateTime.parse('2014-09-01 01:50:00.000')] = 1.26
    ..[DateTime.parse('2014-09-01 01:51:00.000')] = 1.26
    ..[DateTime.parse('2014-09-01 01:52:00.000')] = 1.26
    ..[DateTime.parse('2014-09-01 01:52:00.000')] = 1.26
    ..[DateTime.parse('2014-09-01 01:53:00.000')] = 1.26
    ..[DateTime.parse('2014-09-01 01:54:00.000')] = 1.27
    ..[DateTime.parse('2014-09-01 01:54:00.000')] = 1.27;

  print(identityMap.length); // 13
  identityMap.entries.forEach(print);
  // MapEntry(2014-09-01 01:46:00.000: 1.29)
  // MapEntry(2014-09-01 01:47:00.000: 1.27)
  // MapEntry(2014-09-01 01:48:00.000: 1.27)
  // MapEntry(2014-09-01 01:48:00.000: 1.26)
  // MapEntry(2014-09-01 01:49:00.000: 1.26)
  // MapEntry(2014-09-01 01:50:00.000: 1.26)
  // MapEntry(2014-09-01 01:50:00.000: 1.26)
  // MapEntry(2014-09-01 01:51:00.000: 1.26)
  // MapEntry(2014-09-01 01:52:00.000: 1.26)
  // MapEntry(2014-09-01 01:52:00.000: 1.26)
  // MapEntry(2014-09-01 01:53:00.000: 1.26)
  // MapEntry(2014-09-01 01:54:00.000: 1.27)
  // MapEntry(2014-09-01 01:54:00.000: 1.27)
}
```

If we then want to combine keys which should be seen as equal, we could do something like this:

```dart
void main() {
  final identityMap = Map<DateTime, double>.identity()
    ..[DateTime.parse('2014-09-01 01:46:00.000')] = 1.29
    ..[DateTime.parse('2014-09-01 01:47:00.000')] = 1.27
    ..[DateTime.parse('2014-09-01 01:48:00.000')] = 1.27
    ..[DateTime.parse('2014-09-01 01:48:00.000')] = 1.26
    ..[DateTime.parse('2014-09-01 01:49:00.000')] = 1.26
    ..[DateTime.parse('2014-09-01 01:50:00.000')] = 1.26
    ..[DateTime.parse('2014-09-01 01:50:00.000')] = 1.26
    ..[DateTime.parse('2014-09-01 01:51:00.000')] = 1.26
    ..[DateTime.parse('2014-09-01 01:52:00.000')] = 1.26
    ..[DateTime.parse('2014-09-01 01:52:00.000')] = 1.26
    ..[DateTime.parse('2014-09-01 01:53:00.000')] = 1.26
    ..[DateTime.parse('2014-09-01 01:54:00.000')] = 1.27
    ..[DateTime.parse('2014-09-01 01:54:00.000')] = 1.27;

  // Step 1 - First create a map where we collect all values with the same key
  //          value (based on `==` and `.hashCode`).
  final tempMap = <DateTime, List<double>>{};
  for (final entry in identityMap.entries) {
    tempMap.update(
      entry.key,
      (value) => value..add(entry.value),
      ifAbsent: () => [entry.value],
    );
  }
  tempMap.entries.forEach(print);
  // MapEntry(2014-09-01 01:46:00.000: [1.29])
  // MapEntry(2014-09-01 01:47:00.000: [1.27])
  // MapEntry(2014-09-01 01:48:00.000: [1.27, 1.26])
  // MapEntry(2014-09-01 01:49:00.000: [1.26])
  // MapEntry(2014-09-01 01:50:00.000: [1.26, 1.26])
  // MapEntry(2014-09-01 01:51:00.000: [1.26])
  // MapEntry(2014-09-01 01:52:00.000: [1.26, 1.26])
  // MapEntry(2014-09-01 01:53:00.000: [1.26])
  // MapEntry(2014-09-01 01:54:00.000: [1.27, 1.27])

  // Step 2 - Go though each entry in our `tempMap` and take the average of the
  //          values collected and create a new `Map` based on this.
  final resultMap = tempMap.map((key, value) =>
      MapEntry(key, value.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / value.length));

  resultMap.entries.forEach(print);
  // MapEntry(2014-09-01 01:46:00.000: 1.29)
  // MapEntry(2014-09-01 01:47:00.000: 1.27)
  // MapEntry(2014-09-01 01:48:00.000: 1.2650000000000001)
  // MapEntry(2014-09-01 01:49:00.000: 1.26)
  // MapEntry(2014-09-01 01:50:00.000: 1.26)
  // MapEntry(2014-09-01 01:51:00.000: 1.26)
  // MapEntry(2014-09-01 01:52:00.000: 1.26)
  // MapEntry(2014-09-01 01:53:00.000: 1.26)
  // MapEntry(2014-09-01 01:54:00.000: 1.27)
}
```